# VSCodeVim delete all occurrences containing a pattern

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I would like to delete some prefix from all words in document using VSCodeVim plugin. For example:

```
var someVarOne, someVarTwo, someVarThree;
```

delete prefix 'some' and get:

```
var VarOne, VarTwo, VarThree;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the substitution methods have already been mentioned, you could try this simple method:

1. Visually select the word to be replaced (here it's "some") using the <kbd>v</kbd> key.
2. Place multiple cursors at all places where the word "some" has occurred by 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keys.
3. Delete the visually selected parts using <kbd>d</kbd> key which stands for 
   delete

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
%s/some\(Var\w*\)/\1/g
```

- `\(...\)`  defines a group
- `\w*`  one or more word chars
- `\1` replaced with the first group (whatever matched by `Var\w*`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your var are camelCase as you showed and that only the "some" word is known (i.e., "Var" might change) try this regex:

```
some(([A-Z][a-z]*)+)
```

and replace with `\1`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEEqyo/2).

Works on

> var someVarOne, someVarTwo, someVarThree, someOtherVar, someVar,
>   someThing;
>
> var some;

producing:

> var VarOne, VarTwo, VarThree, OtherVar, Var, Thing;
>
> var some;